# index match using drop down value to execute match

Tags: excel, vba

I've this problem where I want to match two drop down values in order to retrieve value from a range 
This is what I've at the moment, the error I face is, "Unable to get the index property class of the worksheetfunction class"

```
Sub hamtakost()

Dim wbd As Worksheet
Dim wb1 As Worksheet
Dim wb2 As Worksheet
Dim wb3 As Worksheet
Dim DD4 As Object
Dim DD5 As Object

  Set wbd = Worksheets("DASHBOARD")
  Set wb1 = Worksheets("1 år")
  Set wb2 = Worksheets("2-10 år")
  Set wb3 = Worksheets("INDEX")

  wbd.Shapes("Drop Down 4").ControlFormat.RemoveAllItems
  wbd.Shapes("Drop Down 5").ControlFormat.RemoveAllItems

  Set DD4 = wbd.Shapes("Drop Down 4").OLEFormat.Object
  Set DD5 = wbd.Shapes("Drop Down 5").OLEFormat.Object

  test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(wb2.Range("C5:N225"), _
Application.Match(DD4, wb2.Range("B5:B25"), 0), Application.Match(DD4, _
wb2.Range("C3:N3"), 0))

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if you are passing the object in or it's value, maybe get the value from `DD4` and match that?

Comment: Yes it would be easier to paste value somewhere and then get that value, however I would prefer to have all values and formulas in the developer instead of having on a sheet

Comment: you don't need to, press `DD4.` and you can get the value from its properties.

Comment: OK, so you mean using .ListIndex ? or could you show me how to execute it?

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks alot!